# Suppress make warning from not-yet-built include without suppressing error

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If I have a makefile

```
include foo
foo: Makefile
    @echo 'bar::' > foo
    @echo "\t@echo 'bar'" >> foo
bar::
    @echo 'baz'
```

then when I run `make bar`, I get

```
Makefile:1: foo: No such file or directory
bar
baz
```

I want to suppress this warning.  If I have a makefile

```
-include foo
foo: Makefile
    @echo 'bar::' > foo
    @echo "\t@echo 'bar'" >> foo
bar::
    @echo 'baz'
```

then I get, as expected,

```
bar
baz
```

However, if I have a makefile

```
-include foo
bar::
    @echo 'baz'
```

and I run `make bar`, then I get

```
baz
```

while I would instead like to get something like

```
Makefile:1: foo: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo'.  Stop.
```

or at least

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo'.  Stop.
```

How do I suppress the warning without suppressing the error, so that I get a failure if the file cannot be created / if the target does not exist, but no spew when it is successfully created?

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back, and there's no neat solution for it.  the `-include` will simply do nothing if the file doesn't already exist, and the `include` will always throw a warning if the file doesn't exist.   I got around my issue by using a second makefile, but that has its issues as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered an extremely hacky solution, that involves emitting the error message manually:

```
-include foo

ifeq (,$(filter-out foo,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
ifeq (,$(wildcard foo))
$(shell $(MAKE) foo)
ifeq (,$(wildcard foo))
$(error No rule to make target 'foo')
endif
endif
endif

foo: Makefile
    @echo 'bar::' > foo
    @echo "\t@echo 'bar'" >> foo

bar::
    @echo 'baz'
```

Perhaps an ever-so-slightly-less-hacky solution would be:

```
ifeq (,$(filter-out foo,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
ifeq (,$(wildcard foo))
$(shell $(MAKE) foo)
endif
include foo
else
-include foo
endif

foo: Makefile
    @echo 'bar::' > foo
    @echo "\t@echo 'bar'" >> foo

bar::
    @echo 'baz'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a hackish solution:  You could split your makefile into two like so:

```
# Makefile

foo.mak:
    @echo running $@
    @echo 'bar::' > foo.mak
    @echo -e "\t@echo 'bar'" >> foo.mak

bar bar2 bar3: foo.mak
    @$(MAKE) --file Makefile.2 $@
```

and then

```
#Makefile.2:
include foo.mak
bar::
    @echo baz
```

The problem with this is that it has to invoke a new copy of make for each top-level target.   I seem to remember using a match-anything rule instead of a list of explicit targets, but I just tried it, and it seems to be giving me problems, so I listed the targets explicitly.